# Can sql server 2000 and 2012 coexist on the same server?

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012

I see that 2005/2008/2012 can all coexist but can't find anything on 2000 with 2012.

Comment: Just a side note: Sql Server 2000 is less than one year away from it's final end of life (April 9, 2013). That means very soon now it will no longer get any patches, even for critical security issues. Take this as an opportunity to migrate any apps that depend on it.

Comment: it's funny you mention that, because we are currently planning the move of our 2000 databases to 2012!

Comment: I would not suggest side by side as the best way to do this. Try a linked server instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn if there is only one server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I have systems with 2000 and 2012 installed. I have only tried with installing 2000 first though; I haven't been brave enough to try installing 2000 after 2012 was in place.